# Hibernate - Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.podro.model.Journey.roadWay[com.podro.model.RoadElement]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I saw similar questions, but answers weren't helpful. So, i get this error:

```
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.podro.model.Journey.roadWay[com.podro.model.RoadElement]
```

I'm trying to create List with objects of RoadElements (which is interface for class Point and Section). There is any other way to do it? From what i know, i guess that is the only way to create proper mapping for this classes, and have list of this elements.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Journey")
public class Journey {
    // Some other fields
    @Column(name="road_way")
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RoadElement> roadWay;
}


@MappedSuperclass
public interface RoadElement {}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name="Point")
public class Point implements RoadElement{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    @Column(name="time_in_days")
    private int timeInDays;
    private Rate rating;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name="Section")
public class Section implements RoadElement{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="section_name" , length=100)
    private String sectionName;

    @Column(name="time_in_days")
    private int timeInDays;

    @Column(name="kind_of_transport")
    private Locomotion kindOfTransport;

}
```

Thanks for answers, I would be very grateful for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associations are between entities. `RoadElement` is not an entity. It's an interface.

You may not do what you're trying to do. Hibernate needs to know the type of the entities contained in roadWay.

So, RoadElement should be a class, annotated with @Entity, having an ID that uniquely identifies a RoadElement among **all** the road elements (sections, points, etc.)

Section and Point should extend from RoadElement, and should NOT have their own ID, since it's inherited from RoadElement.